# how to convert char array of low and high bytes to int array of them , without using loop?

Tags: c++

I have an uchar array with this arrangement :

`uchar a={LowByte_val1 HighByte_val1 LowByte_val2 HighByte_val2 ...};`

how to i can convert this array to (without loop)

`uint b= [val1 val2 ...];`

where

```
val1 = LowByte_val1+(HighByte_val1<<8);
```

I use this solution.

```
typedef union {
           struct { 
                    uchar lsb; 
                    uchar msb; 
                  }byteModel;
         unsigned int data; 
   }XXX;
```

and

```
uchar a[24]={0,0,0,1,0,2,0,3, 1,0,1,1,1,2,1,3, 2,0,1,1,2,2,2,3}; 
XXX *input = new XXX[12];
```

and then :

```
memcpy(input,a,24);
```

but not worked :(.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why no loops? Just curious, because it sounds a little arbitrary.

Comment: `memcpy` uses a loop.

Comment: Seems you are assuming `int` is 16 bits which is very rare, much less guaranteed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
char c[size];
int *i = (int*)c;
```

This would allow you to access the same data as both an int and a char.

Keep in mind though (as I'm sure you already are) that ints and chars are not the same size. The int array will be much "shorter".

**EDIT:** Someone has pointed out that this only works with little endian architecture. If you need a big endian solution, I will point you to [this tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-endianc/index.html). If you don't know what either of those are, I point you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825632/when-endianess-does-matter-cast-operations) and the above tutorial.

Comment: is there any solution if the arrangement was : uchar a={HighByte_val1 LowByte_val1 HighByte_val2 LowByte_val2 ...};    ????

Comment: @user2087181 Yay! I'm glad.

Comment: @OznOg Please explain. What do you mean by "little endian arch"? Can I read about it somewhere?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825632/when-endianess-does-matter-cast-operations