# Casing pointer (unit8_t to uint16_t) return reversed representation of the bytes

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I am trying to run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<std::uint8_t, 2> one_byte_array;
    one_byte_array[0] = 0xff;
    one_byte_array[1] = 0x00;
    auto ptr8 = one_byte_array.data();
    std::uint16_t* ptr16 = (std::uint16_t*)ptr8;
    std::cout << *ptr16;
    return 0
}
```

[Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/8j2u6)

It outputs :

> 255

I think it should output:

> 65280

Because `0xff` represent the `MSBs` of the new `word` and `0x00` represents the `LSBs` of the new `word`. What did I miss?

Comment: What is the CPU on your machine to run this code? Are you sure the CPU uses big endian?

Comment: You are running on a little-endian machine, and to do such conversions, use type-punning through a union. Otherwise you will break strict aliasing optimizations.

Comment: @MikeCAT, of course, he runs on little-endian. My crystal balls says 'Intel' :)

Comment: @ErikAlapää, union's no good either :)

Comment: @ErikAlapää Type-punning through a union is undefined in C++.

Comment: @molbdnilo Does not matter, all sane compilers and platform support it, it is essential for C and C++ as systems and kernel programming languages.

Comment: @ErikAlapää, post it as an answer so that I can downvote ;)

Comment: @SergeyA: Depends on what you do. For pointer punning, does not work.

Comment: @ErikAlapää: That's your definition of a sane compiler. It ain't mine. My definition is one that implements the standard.

Comment: @Bathsheba The standard is the foundation, but the real world requires more than that.

Comment: Bull. The `memcpy` idiom is correct and no more complicated.

Comment: @Bathsheba Look at real-world code instead of downvoting, maybe you will learn something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of your casts are *undefined*: this is because the types are unrelated.

If you want to coalesce two `uint8_t` into a single `uint16_t` then create an *array* of the former with 2 elements, and `memcpy` that into the `uint16_t`.

(**Don't** consider a `union` of `uint16_t` and an array of `uint8_t` as the behaviour of reading back a union member that wasn't the one you used to set the union's data is *undefined* too.)

Comment: Yup. So close, yet so far!

Comment: Thanks..(std::uint16_t*)ptr8 . This is the UB. Right?

Comment: Yup. The compiler reserves the right to eat your cat if you write that then attempt to deference the pointer. (The data might have different alignment requirements on a particular platform which is a good reason why the language does not define the behaviour).

Comment: @Bathsheba, not exactly. The conversion itself can not lead to cat eating -  - this is just a pointer cast. An access through it (`std::cout << *ptr16`) is cat-eating UB.

Comment: @SergeyA: Indeed you're correct. Amended, but I would still recommend putting your cat in a safe place.

Comment: @Bathsheba, I do not have a cat. Such is life :)

Answer (score 2):

You are violating strict aliasing rule. You can't do this. As for little-endian Intel CPU, this is the least of your worries.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers and comments already mentioned: casting pointers for integral representation is undefined behavior, but what you witnessed has to do with host endianess, which is how the host interprets a series of bytes to form longer words.

Going from a byte buffer (`std::array<std::uint8_t, 2>` in this case) to actual data is called [deserialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) and the easiest way to do this host endianess unaware (assuming buffer is big endian) is to shift the bytes into integrals. For portable serialization of floats, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733147/portability-of-binary-serialization-of-double-float-type-in-c)

```
std::array<std::uint8_t, 2> one_byte_array;
one_byte_array[0] = 0xff;
one_byte_array[1] = 0x00;
uint16_t data = one_byte_array[0] << 8 | one_byte_array[1];
```

Actually, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7180025/104774) already explains it even better.

Another way is to use [ntohs](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html).

```
std::array<std::uint8_t, 2> one_byte_array;
one_byte_array[0] = 0xff;
one_byte_array[1] = 0x00;
uint16_t data;
std::memcpy(&data, one_byte_array.data(), 2);
data = ntohs(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

To do similar conversions, you type-pun through a union, in order to avoid breaking strict aliasing optimizations. See [strict aliasing and type punning](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html)

The important quote is this: 'Strictly speaking, reading a member of a union different from the one written to is undefined in ANSI/ISO C99 except in the special case of type-punning to a char*, similar to the example below: Casting to char*. However, it is an extremely common idiom and is well-supported by all major compilers. As a practical matter, reading and writing to any member of a union, in any order, is acceptable practice.'

Those who talk about UB can sit in their ivory towers for all I care, read the info I linked and learn something instead.

Comment: Eric, what is the point of using unsupported tool instead of using a supported (`memcpy`)?

Comment: @SergeyA For some uses, memcpy is more natural. But the pun-through-union idiom is so common that it has to be supported by compilers, otherwise a LOT of existing code will break. Linus Torvalds himself has quarreled with the gcc people over this, and over strict aliasing optimization.

Comment: Erik, I do not recommend invoking Linus as an authority when discussing with me. I have very little esteem of the Linux as an OS. )) On any rate, what's the benefit?

Comment: @SergeyA AFAIK, unions were designed for this very thing, and it is a clear way of telling a compiler 'these values are of different type but may alias'. Also, AFAIK, type-punning through unions is used in every major OS kernel, and a lot of other mission-critical code. As for quality of Linux - every time I read kernel code, I am impressed at how many good coders work on the kernel, and that they manage to keep up with the breakneck speed Linux evolves. But as for Torvalds, his most creative and cool invention is not Linux, it is Git.